# Output from K&R 1.6 Arrays

Tags: c

From writing the following code:

```
/* 
* Write a program to count the number of occurrences of each digit, of white
* space characters (blank, tab and newline), and of all other characters.
*/

#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

  int c, i, nwhite, nother;
  int ndigit[10];

  nwhite = nother = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
      ndigit[i] = 0;

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
      if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
          ++ndigit[c-'0'];
      else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
          ++nwhite;
      else
          ++nother;
  }

  printf("digits =");
  for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
      printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
  printf(", white space = %d, other = %d\n", 
          nwhite, nother);
  return 0;
}
```

K&R says that the output from this program on itself is:

digits = 9 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1, white space = 123, other = 345

but my output only shows all zeroes. Can someone advise why this is?
(ps the return 0; is not in the book I added that in and the result is the same.)

Comment: Works For Me™. You're probably not feeding the input correctly. What environment are you using? Run the program, paste the code into the terminal, and hit ctrl-D should do it. Whitespace will likely be larger because K&R would be using tab characters to indent instead of individual spaces.

Comment: How are you running the program?

Comment: In linux, you should run it with (assuming the program is called test,c): `.\test < test.c`

Comment: My result:
`digits = 9 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1, white space = 210, other = 445`
I think the differences is caused by local editor configuration.

Comment: Im using NetBeans IDE 8.2 with Cygwin 64 on windows, I press ctrl-D and the output is consistently:                                                                                                              
digits = 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0, white space = 0, other = 0

RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7s)

Comment: I've input this code into https://overiq.com/c-online-compiler/PYl/ and got the same result. eclipse ide isn't recognising EOF and codeblocks isn't showing any output.

Comment: @tdoc The code won't read itself, you have to feed it the input to read. In your online compiler paste the code into the Input box as well. You can see what the program sees as input by printing `c` inside the loop.

Comment: @Schwern Thanks, does this mean I should learn about file pointers to make this work?

Comment: @tdoc In general, yes. For this particular code, no, but you should understand how the code works: what `getchar` does; what stdin is. It might be easier to understand if you replace `getchar` with the equivalent `getc(stdin)`. You need to feed the program input to read. Any input. K&R is offering the source code as input as an example, a possibly confusing one.